# Powershell Import-CSV wont sort

Tags: powershell, csv, sorting, sort-object

In Powershell, I'm attempting to import a CSV file and sort it based on its header name and pipe that to format-table. However I've tried every which way to get it to sort correctly and cant seem to figure it out, any ideas?

CSV:

```
Price,OnHands,Status 
43.73,6,INACTIVE
33,36,CLEARANCE
9.62,3,CLEARANCE
57.8,22,ACTIVE
69.57,16,ACTIVE
22,15,CLEARANCE
```

aka

```
Price  OnHands Status
------ ------- ------
43.73  6       INACTIVE  
33.0   36      CLEARANCE 
9.62   3       CLEARANCE 
57.8   22      ACTIVE    
69.57  16      ACTIVE    
22.0   15      CLEARANCE
```

I've tried the line below, with single, double, and no quotes and as an integer.

```
$data = Import-Csv -Path $PathnNameCSV | Sort-Object -Property 'OnHands' -Descending
```

Also tried just using sort, perhaps my syntax is wrong or the wrong combination somewhere.

```
$data = Import-Csv -Path $PathnNameCSV | sort -Property 'OnHands' -Descending
```

My intended result would be:

```
Price  OnHands Status
------ ------- ------
33.0   36      CLEARANCE 
57.8   22      ACTIVE    
69.57  16      ACTIVE 
22.0   15      CLEARANCE 
43.73  6       INACTIVE 
9.62   3       CLEARANCE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Import-Csv -Path $PathnNameCSV |
    Sort-Object -Property { [int]$_.OnHands } -Descending
```

> ```
> Price OnHands Status   
> ----- ------- -------  
> 33    36      CLEARANCE
> 57.8  22      ACTIVE   
> 69.57 16      ACTIVE   
> 22    15      CLEARANCE
> 43.73 6       INACTIVE 
> 9.62  3       CLEARANCE
> ```

More complex examples at official docs [Use a hash table to sort properties in ascending and descending order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Sort-Object?view=powershell-7#example-5--use-a-hash-table-to-sort-properties-in-ascending-and-descending-order)